# What is the function of label in createDataChannel and how to use it correctly?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using WebRTC, for `createDataChannel`, what is the function of parameter `label`? I didn't find find any info about it.

The API from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#createDataChannel)

> RTCDataChannel createDataChannel (DOMString label, optional
>   RTCDataChannelInit dataChannelDict);

---

And how to use it correctly?

For example, **A** is person who send offer, and **B** is the person who accept the offer, and **they want to send message to each other**, when they use `createDataChannel`,

(Note `---->` means ability to sent message)

(1) Should they use different `label`?

```
createDataChannel(LabelA)
  A ---------------------------> B
    <---------------------------
                         createDataChannel(LabelB)
```

(2) Or they should use same `label`:

```
createDataChannel(Same)
  A ---------------------------> B
    <---------------------------
                         createDataChannel(Same)
```

(3) Or only **A** needs `createDataChannel`, but **B** still can send message back to **A**. Because [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/Lsjv0ub5/2/) is this case.

```
createDataChannel(LabelA)
  A --------------------------> B
    <--------------------------
```

Which case is correct use case? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the value of label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

How you use label is subjective question, I would prefer option 3, a single datachannel for transmitting data two way.

---

from the [WebRTC docs](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcdatachannel), the description of the label attribute of `RTCDataChannel`:

> The label attribute represents a label that can be used to distinguish this RTCDataChannel object from other RTCDataChannel objects. Scripts are allowed to create multiple RTCDataChannel objects with the same label. The attribute MUST return the value to which it was set when the RTCDataChannel object was created.

End of day, label just provides an option for tagging a datachannel.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to get the value of of a label then you can simply get it from the `.label` property. Such as:

```
window.localConnection = localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers,
      pcConstraint);

sendChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel');

console.log('Data channel label: ' + sendChannel.label);
```

You can have a look on webrtc samples: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/datachannel

Comment: Thanks, johannesMatevosyan. I updated my question a little.

Comment: Thank you, johannesMatevosyan!